# Take Union of Select Statement in Loop Of Mysql Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How Take Union of Select Statement in Loop Of Mysql Procedure to get all values from Select Statements in Single Table?
Code:--

```
 iterator:
             Loop
             IF LENGTH(TRIM(_BookingArray)) = 0 OR _BookingArray IS NULL THEN
             LEAVE iterator;
             END IF;
             SET front = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_BookingArray,',',1);
             SET frontlen = LENGTH(front);
             SET TempValue = TRIM(front);
             if not exists(select a.BookingNumber from applicationform a  where a.BookingNumber =TempValue)
    then
                    SELECT TempValue as NotExists;
             end if;
             SET _BookingArray = INSERT(_BookingArray,1,frontlen + 1,'');
             END LOOP;
```

Comment: Everything is working fine as This select statement is Executing multiple times and giving records in different tables.I want to take union of these select statement executing in Loop to get the resut in single table._BookingArray is A parameter in Mysql. Please Refer Below link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/split-a-string-and-loop-through-values-in-mysql-procedure

Comment: I've never seen SET _BookingArray = INSERT(_BookingArray,1,frontlen + 1,'') before and I cannot find a reference in the manual but , hey if it works fine.but I would be nervous of this being around forever.

Comment: _BookingArray  is a parameter in Stored Procedure.In Above link which i have shared is from which i have taken reference to iterate a comma seperated value(Parameter) in mysql Stored Procedure. Now its executing Select statement again and again by iterating comma seperated value ->_BookingArray  .I want to take union of these select statements to get record in single table.

Comment: Well just insert..into..select  either into a permanent table or a temporary table.

Comment: Okk I understand .Is there any other solution??Is Union operator possible to use here?

Comment: I guess you could build a prepared statement and execute it after you exit the loop.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html Search for dynamic sql for examples.